# Showing straight lines through origin are geodesics of Poincare disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit disc. The Poincare metric of $\mathbb D$ is given by $dx^2+dy^2/(1-x^2-y^2)^{-2}.$ I want to show that for $0\neq x\in\mathbb R\cap\mathbb D$ $\gamma_0(t)=tx$ is a geodesic. The usual way to show that for any smooth regular curve $\gamma,$ joining $0$ and $x$ we have that $\text{length}(\gamma)\geq \text{length}(\gamma_0).$ One can show that if $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ then $\text{length}(\gamma)\geq\int_{0}^1|x(t)|/(1-|x(t)|^2)dt$.If we knew that $x$ is a regular cure then we can use change of variable formula and conclude. But we know that $x$ may not be regular. How to resolve this difficulty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a better approach:

1. if a curve is precisely the fixed-point set of an isometry, it is a (reparametrized) geodesic.
2. Isometries take geodesics to geodesics.
3. Rotations about the origin are isometries, so it suffices to check that the vertical diameter is a (reparametrized) geodesic.
4. It is, because it is the fixed point set of the reflection $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$.

No need to bother with lengths and computations.